Efficiently find k-nearest points from a K-d tree to a line using the Point Cloud Library
Using the Point Cloud Library (PCL), I have created a K-d tree from a point cloud. I would like to find the k-nearest points from the K-d tree to a line. Is there a way to do this efficiently using PCL?
Obviously we could use a brute force approach to find the distance of each point from the line and keep the k-nearest points. However, I was hoping that we could use the K-d tree to find the k-nearest neighbors faster.
The octree data structure has a function to find the voxel indices that intersect with a line. However, this does not quite work for my application because it is possible for a line to pass very close to a point which lives in a voxel that does not intersect the line, and so that point would be excluded from the result.

Do you only want to do this one time (one cloud, one line), or many times (one cloud, many lines)? In the first case, I would not use a kdtree/octree. In the second case, I think it is difficult to do something very efficient using only the knn search and radius search functions that PCL exposes for the kdtree. I think your best bet would be to adapt PCL's octree implementation to your needs, by creating a new function that returns the k nearest points to a line. The octree structure would then be used to know which points are worth considering, like in the existing nearestKSearch function

What is efficient? How fast is the current implementation? How fast should it be? How big is the dataset? What does the implementation look like?

@IBitMyBytes, In my application I have one cloud and many lines. Thanks for your comment.

@MarcoF., by efficient I mean faster than brute force search. Brute force search requires O(n) operations to fine the nearest point. With a K-d tree this should be possible in O(log n) operations. Also, the point cloud contains 2M points.

@Andrew I have to determine collisions with lines in various applications. To do this, I iterate along the line with a certain step width and radius and make range queries (nearestKSearch) for each step. You could collect the results of the queries and evaluate the knn to the line.

You have clarified that you want to find the k-nearest points to several lines, so here is my idea from my comment above, but more concrete:
I think your best bet for an efficient solution would be to adapt PCL's octree implementation to your needs, by creating a new function that returns the k nearest points to a line. The octree structure would then be used to know which points are worth considering, like in the existing nearestKSearch function.
You would have to create an adaptation of getKNearestNeighborRecursive (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_search.hpp#L224), and as far as I can see, you would only have to switch out pointSquaredDist (which computes the squared distance between two points) by a function that computes the squared distance between a point and a line (pcl/common/distances.h has functions that do this). And finally, an adaptation of nearestKSearch (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/octree/include/pcl/octree/impl/octree_search.hpp#L82) that calls the recursive function.
Something similar could be possible with a kd-tree, but how easy or difficult this is to implement would depend on the kd-tree implementation.
